# How to rotate an image of CachedNetworkImage in flutter?

Tags: flutter

It's flutter app. It's an app with portrait-only mode.

I want to show some images of my product. When user touches the image,
I would like to show it on full screen using CachedNetworkImage.

But the problem is, when width is bigger than height, Boxfit.cover only shows middle part of image (left and right side not shown). If I make it dispaly all picture, then there'll be so much empty space above and below

I would rather to make the image(CachedNetworkImage) rotate 90 degree, so that whole image can fit the full screen.

Any idea?

Comment: Wrap in RotatedBox to rotate.

Comment: There are plenty of way in which you can achieve it, easy one is to wrap inside `Transform.rotate()` and set an `angle:90`